# Not showing typed words correctly in JavaFX with jdk8 in Windows

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a client application using javafx, and I saw some typing errors in jdk 8. I'm using Myanmar font, in jdk 7, I can see the typed words correctly like the following screen shot when I type q + `(typekey) + q.

[image]

But in jdk8, it shows like the following with incorrect format.
[image]

Its working perfectly on Mac OS, but not in Windows.
I don't know it is the jdk8's problem or not. Please help me to solve that problem.

Here is my code.`

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {        
    VBox hbox = new VBox(7);
    TextField text = new TextField();
    text.setPrefHeight(40);

    Button btn1 = new Button();
    btn1.setText("Something");
    btn1.setMinWidth(110);      

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(text,btn1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Version Updater");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(500);
    primaryStage.setHeight(350);
    primaryStage.show();    
}`
```

Comment: Please include code snippet which indicates, how are you using font. It will help others to pinpoint exact cause.

Comment: I just use the TextField normally bro. I just switch the keyboard to type myanmar font. It's just not working with jdk8 on Windows. Thank u..

Comment: may be myanmar font is unavailable in windows

Comment: As I mention in first screen shot with jdk7, it works perfectly. It's just not working well in jdk8 on windows. Thank u.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest JDK version which is 121. I had rendering issues with earlier versions.

Comment: I've already tested with jdk121 bro. It's also not working. Thank u bro.

Comment: Don't thank everyone coz It looks like your problem is solved then :p

Comment: On Windows Vista, 7, and 8, the JRE supports use of any keyboard layout or IMM-based input method. `Input methods implemented in the Java programming language are supported in all components but JavaFX nodes, on all versions of Windows.` ref http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html. if it works on mac os then update your jdk on windows

Comment: Oh.. what u mentioned is a great source bro, minigeek. It looks like it's still not supporting in Windows. It said "The JRE supports use of any input source." for Mac. So, it got in mac. Let me thank u :-D